# COUNT records in RANGE GROUP BY date

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, group-by

I have a sales table that shows the date and time of each sale.

For example:

**saleid | saledate |    saletime**
1   | 20110327 | 101
2  | 20110327 | 102
3  | 20110328 | 201

(So sale 2 occurred on 20110327 at 102)

I need to construct a single SQL statement that:
Groups the sales by date (each row is a different date) and then
counts the sales for each time range.  (With each time range being a separate column)

The table should look something like this:

**saledate  |  101-159 |  200-259 |**
20110327  | 2 |   0 |
20110328  | 0       |  1 |

It needs to be a single statement and saledate and saletime need to remain in numeric format.
(I am pulling from a database table with several million rows)

I am using MS Access

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I've been too long away from MS access to answer this fully, but as a hint, research pivot queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT saledate,
SUM(IIF(saletime >= 101 and saletime <= 159), 1, 0) as [101To159)
SUM(IIF(saletime >= 200 and saletime <= 259), 1, 0) as [200To259)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY saledate
```

Note: I haven't run this query. However, this is how it could be.

Comment: Isn't this what the Partition() function is for?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT saledate,
SUM(case when saletime between 101 and 159 then 1 else 0 end ) as R101_159,
SUM(case when saletime between 200 and 259 then 1 else 0 end ) as R200_59
FROM myTable
GROUP BY saledate
```